# What is the correct way to test a type is bare typing.Dict in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to write a function `is_bare_dict` to return True for `Dict` and false for any typed dict such as `Dict[int, str]`.

One way I could come up with is something like this:

```py
from typing import Dict, KT, VT

def is_bare_dict(typ) -> bool:
    ktype = typ.__args__[0]
    vtype = typ.__args__[1]
    return ktype is KT and vtype is VT
```

You can run the above code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/sr9mGbWo3Lh7VrPh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def is_typing_dot_dict(typ) -> bool:
    return typ is typing.Dict
```

If you really want to test whether something is `typing.Dict`, then just do that. It's likely not the correct thing to test for, though - it seems likely that you'd also want to treat `dict` the same, and perhaps `typing.Dict[Any, Any]`. (Also, `typing.Dict` is deprecated and probably going away eventually.)

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done in one line

```
from typing import Dict, KT, VT

def is_bare_dict(typ) -> bool:
    return not isinstance(typ.__args__, tuple)


print(is_bare_dict(Dict)) # Print True
print(is_bare_dict(Dict[int, str])) # Print False
```